# CoreData can't save Object when non-Optional value is set in willSave()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

**Context**
I have a non-Optional `lastEditTS` `Attribute` on an `Entity`, which I set every time the method `willSave()`gets called.
However, this results in the following Saving error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "lastEditTS is a required Value.\ ...

---

**Code**

```swift
public override func willSave() {
    lastEditTS = .now
    super.willSave()
}
```

---

**Question:**

- How can lastEditTS be nil when saving the context?

Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed objects are validated before they're saved. Internally, Core Data validates your property values first and only saves if they're OK. In your case, since `lastModified` is nil when you try to save changes, validation fails. Your `willSave` function never gets called because validation already failed, so it has no effect.

You can override validation to make it work. It doesn't work quite like it seems at first-- you can't just set a value for `lastModified`. You need to modify the incoming value directly. Something like this:

```
@objc public func validateLastModified(_ value: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws {
    if lastModified == nil {
        value.pointee = Date.now as AnyObject
    }
}
```

You don't call `super` here because `validateLastModified` doesn't exist there. You **must** check the value of `lastModified` and only change it if necessary, because Core Data will call validation again with your new value. If you change it every time you'll get stuck in an infinite validation loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I still get the same error saying, that the lastEditTS is empty and a required field. Any idea why this still comes up?

Comment: Sorry, the function name is wrong. It should be `validateLastEditTS`.